# MooTools accordion mouseover

Tags: mootools, accordion, mouseover

I saw on the internet a accordion with mootools. But this is a click-event. I want to have a mouseover for to open the accordion. I have tied, but it doesn't work.

Can someone help me? Thanks in advance

```js
window.addEvent('domready', function() 
{
    var myAccordion = new Accordion
    (
        $('accordion'), 'div.toggler', 'div.element', 
        {

        opacity: false,
        display: 0,
        alwaysHide: true,


        // WHEN A PART IS OPEN
        onActive: function(toggler, element)
        {
            toggler.setStyle('color', '#FF4A6F');
        },

        // WHEN A PART IS CLOSED
        onBackground: function(toggler, element)
        {
            toggler.setStyle('color', '#585858');
        }

    // END ACCORDION H3, DIV.ELEMENT
    }
// END VAR NEW ACCORDION
);
// END FUNCTION
});
```

my html:

```js
 <div id="homeBox_img">
                        <div id="slideshow-container">
                            <img src="img/image1.jpg"  width="345" height="301" alt="introducing img" />
                            <img src="img/image2.jpg"  alt="introducing img" />
                            <img src="img/image3.jpg" width="345" height="301" alt="introducing img" />

                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Keep in mind that might produce some strange behaviour since while the accordion is expanding the `hover` might end up in another toggler... Anyway, you could either build your own accordion or attach a `fireEvent()` to the toggler on mouse over. If you post your HTML maybe we can help better.

Answer (score 1):

To build an accordion successfully, there must be the collection of toggler elements ( like `h2` elements in example below ), and the collection of content elements ( '`.content`' ). I do not see what html that you have added has to do with the script, but here is an basic example where the change of elements is triggered with '`mouseenter`' event.

**JS**:

```
new Fx.Accordion(
    '#accordion h2', '#accordion .content', { trigger: 'mouseenter' }
);
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="accordion">
    <h2>image1</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/image1.jpg" width="345" height="301" alt="introducing img" />
    </div>
    <h2>image2</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/image2.jpg" width="345" height="301" alt="introducing img" />
    </div>
    <h2>image3</h2>
    <div class="content">
        <img src="img/image3.jpg" width="345" height="301" alt="introducing img" />
    </div>
```

http://mootools.net/docs/more/Fx/Fx.Accordion#Fx-Accordion
http://mootools.net/demos/?demo=Accordion